# Using MySQL in Powershell, how do I pipe the results of my script into a csv file?

Tags: mysql, windows, csv, piping

In PowerShell, how do I execute my mysql script so that the results are piped into a csv file? The results of this script is just a small set of columns that I would like copied into a csv file.

I can have it go directly to the shell by doing:

```
mysql> source myscript.sql
```

And I have tried various little things like:

```
mysql> source myscript.sql > mysql.out
mysql> source myscript.sql > mysql.csv
```

in infinite variation, and I just get errors. My db connections is alright because I can do basic table queries from the command line etc... I haven't been able to find a solution on the web so far either...

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` ? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to not be running powershell, but the mysql command line tool (perhaps you started it in a powershell console though.)

Note also that the mysql command line tool cannot export directly to csv.

However, to redirect the output to a file just run

```
mysql mydb < myscript.sql >mysql.out
```

or e.g.

```
echo select * from mytable |  mysql mydb >mysql.out
```

(and whatever arguments to mysql you need, like username, hostname)

Comment: For the first one, I tried it in both shell and mysql commandline (running in shell). I either get "'>' character reserved for future use" or I am told I have a syntax error (when I try running within mysql terminal).  Pretty new at this :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: @yunje you should not run this in the mysql terminal. Run it in your cmd.exe or powershell

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for SELECT INTO OUTFILE ? dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html – Pekka 19 hours ago

Yep. Select into outfile worked! But to make sure you get column names you also need to do something like:

```
select *
from
(
 select 
 a,
 b,
 c
 )
 Union ALL
(Select *
from actual)
```